Extend content height side by side
So here I have 2 column layout with some content like header, sub-title, horizontal rule, another text and a list. (Please refer to two screenshots attached)
The container (main column) is able to display the same height as per the large content perfectly.
But I am facing issues when aligning containers like sub-title, horizontal rule and list content.
Any idea if I can achieve this perfectly aligned layout side by side using CSS?


Problem


2. How it needs to be
